# how to scrape pop up window in python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Just new to python and beautiful soup here i have this html below that i need to scrape the href link in the table as well as all the text from td tags.

I was able to scrape hrefs by:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#lstDocTable tbody tr td:nth-child(0) a")
print([link.get_attribute("href") for link in links])
```

Still struggling on on the all the `data(rows)` in the table. thoughts?

Clicking a link will show this pop up:

[image]

Comment: I actually got it! by using .text links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#lstDocTable tbody tr td:nth-child(2) a")
print([link.text for link in links])

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it! by using .text

links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#lstDocTable tbody tr td:nth-child(2) a") print([link.text for link in links])